# Weblogic - how to bring server down for maintenance?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I need to bring down a server in Weblogic 10.3 (which will have only one application deployment) and display a "Under Maintenance" page when the user requests the application.

Is there a way to use two managed servers or WLST to do this somehow?

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is to proxy requests through nginx or apache (or tomcat for that matter)
My second thought is that you put the managed severs in a cluster, and when the app goes offline, cluster resolves to the managed server that displays Under Maintenance page.
Third thought is if dns resolves to myserver.mydomain.com:9333/ you can stop one managed server and start the other and your customers won't know the diff
wonder how cache in the customer browser affects this?

Comment: Thanks - I found information on using Apache and Weblogic together with an Apache plugin that tunnels HTTP requests from Apache to Weblogic. 

However, what ended up doing in the end is using an Application mapped to "/" that had a error-page descriptor in the web.xml. This works but only if I stop the one application. If I wanted to stop the whole server, I think I would try the Apache solution. Thanks!